# OpenMediaVault5 NAS [RAID Management] "State: clean, degraded", [File Systems] "Status: Missing"

Tags: nas, raid-5, openmediavault

I do have a NAS that runs OpenMediaVault5 (version:5.5.13-1 (Usul)), use 11 HDD in RAID5 and that have (actually had till today) available 12TB of space. From this morning, all over the sudden, it started to show available only 65GB, which I suspect that actually is the drive on which OpenMediaVault5 is installed on. In order to not waste space, I've installed OpenMediaVault5 on an old 80GB (74.53GB real space) SATA drive.

I do suspect that something went wrong with the RAID management, here's why:

- Storage->Disks, all the disk are listed, so they are seen be the system.
- Storage->S.M.A.R.T.->Devices, all the HDD are shown and the status is "OK" (the green dot).
  Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/6J7Z7kd/01.png
- Storage-> Logical Volume Management -> Physical Volumes, is only shown one device (with Available: 1.82TiB, Used: 1.82TiB), which should be more devices than this one.
  Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/C6h6pRT/02.png
- Storage-> Logical Volume Management -> Volume Groups, is one volume group, (Available: 9.10 TiB, Free: 0.00B, Physical volumes: [unknown]/dev/md126)

Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/JFs5J2n/03.png

- Storage-> Logical Volume Management -> Logical volumes, only one, with a Capacity: 9.10TiB, Active: No. In my opinion there should be and additional Logical Volume, and beside Active, for this existing one, should be "Yes", instead of "No".
  Screenshot: ttps://i.ibb.co/ydCYbZC/04.png
- Storage-> RAID Management, it's only one RAID device, which should be couple of them in fact. For the existing one, the "State" is "clean, degraded", Level: Capacity 1.82TiB
  Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/YfDZ445/05.png
- Storage-> File Systems, one out of 6 File Systems devices, have the Status: Missing, for "Mounted" column it looks like one out of 4 (the 80GB HDD) is mounted (the other 3 are not, being mentioned "No")
  Screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/5BhRnNF/06.png

I don't know what to do at the moment in order to:
a. diagnosed and full understand the problem and what caused it.
b. have the data from these 11HDD safe, while I've trying to sort this out.
c. to repair and remount the missing RAID devices without loosing any data, to get back access to all HDDs.

for the Past month, I need to confess, I've turned OFF my OMV5 NAS, only by using the power button, long pressing it, and my fear is that on a medium to long term, this can cause some internal errors, or software error that lead to the RAID management problems.
What do you think, what could be the cause of the problem and how can it be solved?

I will try to do my best to remember how they were connected almost 3 years ago, when this NAS was created.

1. **1 x 80 GB HDD** (ST3802110AS, 74.53GB) used only for OS (OMV5), **stand alone**.
2. **10 HDD** out of all 11 HDD were **part of the same LVM** (Logical Volume Manager) distributed as follows:
   a). **2 x 6TB HDD in RAID1** (ST6000VX0023-2EF110 , ST6000VN001-2BB186 with 5.46TB, each)
   b). **3 x 3TB HDD in RAID5** (HUS724030ALA640, ST3000DM008-2DM166, WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0, with 2.73TB, each).
   c). **2 x 2 TB HDD in RAID 1** (2 x ST2000DM001-1CH164)
   d). **3 x 500 GB HDD in RAID 5** (ST3500312CS, ST3500418AS, WDC WD5000AADS-00S9B0, 465.76 GB, each)

A friend of mine, who's a DevOps Team Lead and a Linux expert, he discovered that OMV is based on Debian, and helped me to create the put the HDD in RAID, to create LVM and everything else need it, using PuTTY. He tried to configure the HDDs in such a way to get the most from my disks and keep my data as safe as possible.

**[UPDATE 1]:**
Here's the **output** (from **PuTTY**), that could help you to better understand my situation:

**cat /proc/mdstat**

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md2 : inactive sdc1[1](S)
      488252391 blocks super 1.2

md126 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdb2[1](S) sdf2[3] sdj2[0]
      1953239040 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [U_U]
      bitmap: 7/8 pages [28KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : inactive sdb1[1](S) sdf1[5](S) sdi1[3](S) sdj1[0](S) sde1[2](S)
      9766901955 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

**blkid**

```
​$ blkid
-sh: 148: blkid: not found
```

**fdisk -l | grep "Disk "**

```
​$ fdisk -l | grep "Disk "
-sh: 152: fdisk: not found
```

**cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf**

```
​$ cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# This file is auto-generated by openmediavault (https://www.openmediavault.org)
# WARNING: Do not edit this file, your changes will get lost.

# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
# Note, if no DEVICE line is present, then "DEVICE partitions" is assumed.
# To avoid the auto-assembly of RAID devices a pattern that CAN'T match is
# used if no RAID devices are configured.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>
# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR vic**********@**********.com
MAILFROM root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
#INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md4 metadata=1.2 name=t-black:4 UUID=e26095ea:568e0e54:55a79e83:5f9eda43
#INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md126 metadata=1.2 name=localhost.localdomain:2 UUID=c3912ec0:9fd283df:d5ff048b:9effd01b
```

**mdadm --detail --scan --verbose**

```
​$ mdadm --detail --scan --verbose
-sh: 186: mdadm: not found
```

I do hope that you will be able to confirm that this mess that I'm in, can be sort out without loosing data, cause at this stage, I'm not able to get anything from this PuTTy output.

**[UPDATE 2]:**
On the advice of a forum member, I've tried:

```
​$ mdadm --readwrite /dev/md126
```

, and I've got:
"
mdadm: failed to set writable for /dev/md126: Device or resource busy
"

```
​$ mdadm --assemble --force --verbose /dev/md127 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdf1  dev/sdi1 /dev/sdj1 /dev/sde1
```

, and I've got:
"
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md127
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: dev/sdi1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdj1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is busy - skipping
"

At this stage I feal hopeless, but who know, maybe there's still hope for me.

Thank you in advance for your help.